# How to replace the values of the properties of an object by it's type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, types

Let's consider a variable **obj**, which is defined as :

```
var obj = {
  one: "I am a String",
  two: {},
  three: 3,
  four: []
}
```

Now, let's imagine a function named **replaceWithType()**, which can be used sometjing like this :

```
var type = replaceWithType(obj)
console.log(JSON.stringify(type))
```

This outputs :

```
{"one":"string","two":"object","three":"number","four":"array"}
```

So, thus you can see, that the **replaceWithType()**, replaces the value with their types, but I am not understanding how to build this function. So, can you give me a quick demo of how can this be done ?

Comment: Have you tried ```obj[objKey] = typeof obj[objKey]``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete example with the latest [ECMAScript standard defined nine types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures): `undefined`, `Boolean`, `Number`, `String`, `BigInt`, `Symbol`, `null`, `Object`, `Function` (array is not one of them, but I've included it nonetheless):

```js
var obj = {
    one: "I am a String",
    two: {},
    three: 3,
    four: [],
    five: () => {},
    six: null,
    seven: undefined,
    eight: true,
    nine: 1n,
    ten: Symbol(1),
  },
  result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
      let type;
      switch (true) {
        case Array.isArray(v):
          type = "array";
          break;
        case v === null:
          type = "null";
          break;
        default:
          type = typeof v;
      }
      return [k, type];
    })
  );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const obj = {
  one: "I am a String",
  two: {},
  three: 3,
  four: []
}

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    a[k] = Array.isArray(v) ? 'array' : typeof v;
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map all entries with their types and get a new object from it.

```js
var obj = { one: "I am a String", two: {}, three: 3, four: [] },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(obj)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, Array.isArray(v) ? 'array' : typeof v])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {
    one: "I am a String",
    two: {},
    three: 3,
    four: []
}

Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    obj[key] = typeof obj[key]
})

console.log(obj)
```

What we're doing here, is:

- First using `Object.keys()` function to make an array of keys from
  the object, so we can iterate through them.
- Then use the `array.prototype.map()` function to go through each one. You can treat `.map()` like a more convenient for loop.
- And finally, we swap each element of the object with it's type, by
  using the `typeof` operator which returns the type of a value. And this syntax `obj[value]` is the same as saying `obj.value`